# ember-cli-chart Getting beginAtZero to work

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to edit the options for displaying a chart using ember-cli-chart.

Here is my code:

```
// hbs template
{{ember-chart type="Line" data=journeyData options=lineOptions height=100 width=400}}

// route
journeyData: Ember.computed('model.journey', function(){
    return {
        labels: this.get('model.journey').mapBy('date'),
        datasets: [{
            label: "Emissions",
            fill:false,
            tension: 0,
            fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            strokeColor: "#4caf50",
            data: this.get('model.journey').mapBy('emissions'),
        }]
    }
}),
lineOptions: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                max: 5,
                min: 0,
                stepSize: 0.5,
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
}
```

This is set out as the documentation says but none of the options under 'scales' are working. The responsive and maintainAspectRatio options work.

Have I put it in the correct place?

Comment: Have your tried setting the data in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
lineOptions: {
    scaleBeginAtZero: true, // ADDED
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display:true,
        ticks: {
          max:         5,
          min:         0,
          stepSize:    0.5,
        }
      }]
    },
    responsive:          true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
  }
```